# What is this wpf multitrigger condition used for?

Tags: wpf, combobox, properties, triggers, conditional-statements

I tried to redefine the wpf combobox design. I found different solutions online, and one of these was to right click on the combobox in the designer and then select "EditTemplate/Edit Copy" which is supposed to create a ControlTemplate based on the default combobox template.

Unfortunatly, I got the following error : "Must have non-null value for Property".

I found it was related to triggers and tried to identify where the error came from, since VS would not point it out.

I finally found the trigger which is defined as :

```
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
      <Condition>
        <Condition.Value>
          <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
        </Condition.Value>
      </Condition>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

So there actually is a Condition with an undefined Property property and it seems like it's waiting for something to be false in order to trigger....

I'm trying to understand that condition.

(I remember seeing such conditions on other SO posts but couldn't find them back...)

Comment: Perhaps somebody was trying to write a XAML equivalent of `if (false) {...}` -- disable the trigger without commenting it or deleting it. But they did it wrong.

Comment: The second `Condition` has no `Property` set.

Answer (score 0):

A `<Condition>` is supposed to have a `Property` but your second hasn't:

```
<Condition>
    <Condition.Value>
        <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
    </Condition.Value>
</Condition>
```

Remove it or set its `Property` property to the name of the property that should be false for the condition to apply:

```
<Condition Property="SomeProperty">
```

There is no such thing as an "undefined `Property`". That's what the error message "Must have non-null value for `Property`" means.

Comment: As mentioned in my post : I am aware that the Property property is missing, but this is Visual Studio generated code and i'm wondering why it generated such syntax :/

Comment: @AxelSamyn: Probably because you haven't specified a property name. Don't rely on the designer to generate code for you.

Comment: Well I guess you're right, but since VS told me this code is part of the default combobox template, I expected it to compile at least :/

Comment: It may not be able to resolve some bindings when extracting the template. I don't know about this one though. Where in what template is the condition defined?